# Why is my 7 segment display using CD4511 IC not working. Circuit Design attached

Tags: seven-segment-display, tinkercad, bread-board

I want to count 0 to 9 by converting decimal to BCD in Arduino. Then sent it to CD4511 decoder which translates it to a seven-segment display. But it is not working. Please help. Photo of circuit and arduino code is attached.[`circuit design is as follows:-`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPZ5x.png)

the  Arduino code for decimal to BCD is from 0 to 9 is `

```
    void setup(){
        pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
    }

void loop()
{



    int a,b,c,d;
    for (int x=0;x<10;x++){
    a=x%2;
    b=(x/2)%2;
    c=(x/4)%2;
    d=(x/8)%2;
    digitalWrite(1,a );
    digitalWrite(2,b );
    digitalWrite(3,c );
    digitalWrite(4,d );
  }

   
  
 }
```

`